# Android info button, new Activity or not?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have to add a "info" button in my appliation of image retouching, so typically it's just a "i" logo in the menu bar, and when you click on it a list of severals values is showed on the entire screen with a back button at top-left.

I just want to know what is the best practice to do this. For me because it's a new screen I must use a new Activity. And not a Fragment because I want to have the same behavior on tablet. However may be it's better to do a fragment if in the futur I want to develop the informations on the half of the screen for tablets. But may be it's better to just switch content of the layout or setVisible()  a part of it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider using a dialog for that instead of an activity or fragmdnt?

Comment: Yes but I prefer have a behavior of a pane on the entire screen, and to know how to do it. Your solution escape to the problem ^^